# Как определить метафору

Tags: тропы, метафора

Есть ли в этих предложениях метафоры? Я выделила - политический театрик, высокие кабинеты - это синекдоха?или как метафору можно;маринуется в нижегородских приемных; пускают по большому кругу; прошмыгивал мышкой. Или я неправильно понимаю метафору? помогите разобраться

> > 1)И чем дальше продвигалось расследование, чем больше фактов вытаскивалось из пыльных кулис политического театрика – тем яснее и страшнее становилась истина.
> >     2)Например, «протестанты» имеют доступ в любые высокие кабинеты буквально круглосуточно, их зовут на закрытые совещания, прислушиваются к каждому чиху.
> >     3)В это же время застройщик, имеющий на руках все документы, маринуется в нижегородских приемных часами и месяцами.
> >     4)Представителей дольщиков будущего жилья, включая обитателей ветхого фонда, вообще чинуши пускают по «большому кругу» — это когда все говорят «да», но требуют еще одно согласование, подпись, справку, цифру.
> >     5)Мимо штаба непримиримый борец с тоталитарным режимом прошмыгивал мышкой.

Answer (score 1):

**Метафора** — перенос наименования с одной реалии на другую по сходству признаков. Метафору называют **скрытым сравнением**, так как  предмет сравнения не назван.

1) Постановочная, рассчитанная на зрителя деятельность политической структуры сравнивается  с театром. **Метафора.**

2) Высокие кабинеты — высокопоставленные чиновники в этих кабинетах. **Метонимия:** перенос "помещение — те, кто находится в помещении".

Очень внимательно слушать: прислушиваться к каждому чиху. **Гипербола** (преувеличение).

3) Долго ждать — мариноваться. Мариновать. Разг. Намеренно задерживать решение, исполнение чего-л. **Словесная метафора** (овеществление), отмечена в словаре.

4) Пускать  по «большому кругу» — по образцу  "пускать по замкнутому кругу", то есть склонять к тщетным действиям. **Фразеологизм построен на метафоре.**

5) Борец с тоталитарным режимом прошмыгивал мышкой. Борец как мышка, **сравнение**.